# ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery'

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery'

The code is running fine in my local machine. when i run this code on azure server then create this issue.

I also renamed `celery.py` file to `celeryy.py` file and then checked the error is still same.

here below is my project file structure in below screenshot.

[image]

`__init__.py` file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from core.celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

`celery.py` file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

app = Celery('core')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

`task.py` file:

```
from celery import shared_task
from time import sleep
from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread
from django.core.mail import send_mail
token = lib.auth()
adls_client = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name='bnlweda04d3232gsdfs')

@shared_task
def sleepy(duration):
    sleep(duration)
    return None
    
@shared_task
def send_email_task(subject,message,from_email,recipient_email,fail_silently):
    sleep(30)
    send_mail(
        subject,message,from_email,recipient_email,fail_silently
    )
    return 'Mail sent success'
```

I'm using celery version: `4.4.0` and python version: `3.8.10`

Comment: Don't name your module `celery.py` as you are almost certainly getting a naming conflict with the `celery` package.

Comment: okay. so you mean i have to change that name except `celery`.@FiddleStix

Comment: I renamed `celery.py` file to `celeryy.py` and still the error is same

Answer (score 24):

I had this exact same issue the way you described, and it started happening only recently (CI failed Oct 3, 2022 but worked fine Sep 25, 2022, with no related changes in between).

What ended up being the cause was the fact that in my CI, `importlib-metadata` started installing version `5.0.0`, which gave the error (Worked fine with `4.12.0`).

To fix it for now, I just added `importlib-metadata==4.13.0` to my `environment.yml`  file, after which the issue was solved.

Comment: This is a bug in celery that they fixed with a new version. https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/7783

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/python/importlib_metadata/issues/411

Downgrade importlib-metadata to 4.13.0.

Answer (score 1):

**A shorten Answer:**
Your problem here is that you've named a submodule (aka a python file)
or a package (aka a folder) with the same name of the package that you want to import `celery` therefore you need to change the name of this file in order to import the correct package.

**More details:**
Python importing module checks the packages name in the paths specified ordered in `sys.path`. So if you printed

```
print(sys.path)
```

You will get a list of paths at where the interpreter will start to search for the package name in the same order, and the first path is your current directory path so once it finds it in your current working directory it will import it and wouldn't continue searching.

for more details you can read the documentation from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: I renamed `celery.py` file to `celeryy.py` and still the error is same.

Comment: I am supposing that you've already did `pip install celery` in the same working environment didn't you ?

Comment: yes.  I have installed in the same working environment .

Comment: Any idea why the error still happens even though you changed the name to celeryy.py?

Answer (score 0):

Install it by placing your cursor on red underline and then select install pkg or press alt+shift+enter